# Allow mutiple check out of files with VSS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

Does anyone know how to enable multiple checkout for file in vss6.0?
Currently it won't even allow to edit the file if it is checked out by another user.

Comment: am i asking the invalid question??no replies yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable 'Allow multiple checkouts' at SourceSafe Administrator-> Tools->Options.

[This article](http://www.codepool.biz/version-control/sourcesafe/lock-modify-unlock-or-copy-modify-merge.html) includes more details.